# tkz-euclide, define points outside of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, programming, tkz-collection

Is it possible to define points in tkz-euclide outside of the tikzpicture environment?

For example I would like to have something like this exercise in elementary geometry:

```
Exercise:

Consider the triangle $\Delta$ defined by the points \definePoint{A,2,3}, 
\definePoint{B,10,3} and \definePoint{C,-1,4}. 
Draw the inscribed circle and the circumscribed circle of this triangle.

Solution:

\begin{tikzpicture}
% The triangle
%A,B,C are defined in the exercise above
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)

% circumcircle
\tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzDrawPoint(G)
\tkzDrawCircle(G,A)

% incircle
\tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{rIN}
\tkzDrawPoint(I)
\tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rIN pt)

\tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](A,I,G)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The point is, that if I modify the coordinates of the Points A,B,C in the question, the points in the solution should be modified too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any official way to do this.
TikZ seems to remembers the position of nodes between pictures, but I think this is mostly an unintended side-effect of the way nodes a stored, rather than anything officially supported. Anyway, you can write

```
\tikz \tkzDefPoint(1,2){A};
```

and the position of A will be know in the next picture (or technically until a new node with name A is defined).

It might be nicer to store the point definitions in a hook and add them at the beginning of the `tikzpicture`, as done in the following code. That way, one doesn't have to rely on undocumented features and can use the `label` option of `\tkzDefPoint`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\makeatletter
% Define a point for use in the next TkZ drawing.
%
% Takes 2 mandatory and one optional argument:
%  * The optional argument is passed as optional argument to \tkzDefPoint.
%  * The first mandatory argument is the name of the point, e.g. “A”.
%  * The second mandatory argument is the coordinates of the point (without parenthesis).
%
% The macro also adds $name = (coordinates)$ to the text.
%
% To actually add the points to a tikzpicture, you need to call \definedPoints
% at the start of the tikzpicture.
\newcommand*\definePoint[3][]{%
    \g@addto@macro\tsx@pointhook{\tkzDefPoint[#1](#3){#2}}%
    $#2=(#3)$%
}

% hook to store the points until they are used
\def\tsx@pointhook{}

% Print anything in the hook and clear in afterwards.
\newcommand\definedPoints{%
    \tsx@pointhook%
    \gdef\tsx@pointhook{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Consider the triangle $\Delta$ defined by the points \definePoint[label=above:$A$]{A}{2,3}, 
\definePoint{B}{8,3} and \definePoint{C}{-1,-1}. 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % The triangle
    % A,B,C are defined in the exercise above
    \definedPoints
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to modify this, that it is possible to reuse the identifier A later in the text for another point, for example one may append this to your example: 
`Consider another triangle $\Delta_2$ defined by the points \definePoint[label=above:$A$]{A}{1,3},
\definePoint{B}{2,3} and \definePoint{C}{-1,-1}.


\begin{tikzpicture}
% The triangle
%A,B,C are defined in the exercise above
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @user: Do you mean that the same definition should be used in a second tikzpicture?

Comment: @Caramdir: If I use the points A,B,C from your example in a second tikzpicture, there is no problem. However, I want to redefine A, B and C after the first tikzpicture. I tried this, but it has no effect. (Just append the code from my last comment and see what happens).

Comment: @user You need to add `\definedPoints` in every tikzpicture where you want to use the defined points.